# Two Raspberries communicating each other

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm due to prepare two raspberries talking each other through python program. Before starting I would understand which is the easiest way to do so. More precisely, Raspberry A receives an input to GPIO. A python code read the status of GPIO and sends an input to raspberry B that is read by an other python code. Raspberry B python code sends back to Raspberry A a message for doing something. The two raspberries are on the same network.
How can I implement the communication through network between the two raspberries? What should I use for sending and receiving inputs over network?
Many thanks for the help

Comment: There a loads of protocols. You can use tcp/udp or higher level protocols like http.

Comment: can't you connect the 2 raspberry with ethernet or with a switch, and then get the ip of the 2 raspberry, and in your programm you use standard sockets. One of them is the server, the other is the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a TCP socket server on Raspberry B and a corresponding TCP socket client on Raspberry A. You will find plenty of examples and tutorials how to do this in detail. Read the python docs about socket types and flags.

Basically you have to import the socket library (import socket) and create a socket object, like this:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

On the server side you bind the servers own ip address and any arbitrary unused port to the socket, then start listening for incoming requests:

```
sock.bind('192.168.1.35', 9050)
sock.listen(1)  # allow only 1 connection
connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
try:
  # Receive the data
  while True:
    data = connection.recv(128)   # the buffer in this example is 128 bytes
    if data:
    :
    : do something with the received data and
    : send the modified data back as response
    :
    connection.sendall(data)
    else:
      break

finally:
  # Clean up the connection
  connection.close()
```

On the client side, again you first create a corresponding socket but then connect it to the listening remote servers ip address and port.

```
sock.connect('192.168.1.35', 9050)  # connect to remote server
```

You can monitor your GPIO in a loop and send the data using sendall. Make sure your receive buffer on the server side is big enough to hold the data you send.

```
# Send data
socket.sendall(data)

# Look for the response
data = client_socket.recv(128)   # Make sure the buffer is big enough
```

Wen you are finished you can close the connection:

```
client_socket.close()
```

This is basically all you need for your communication as long you don't need asynchronous communication or more than one connection at a time. As I don't know how you monitor the GPIO and what you want to do with the responses I didn't go into further details on the client side.

Comment: many thanks, it is the explanation I needed for "socket" solution that you confirm it's the best way. For your info I'm trying to build a system for a door bell (Raspy A) and automatic response, probably also by voice, from Raspy(s) B.